# "Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context" error when i run Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am getting this below Error while i run my protractor. And below is the error as shown in my webstorm console.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2\bin\runnerw.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js
>   C:\Users\x216526\workspace_Protractor\SWA_Protractor\conf.js
>   [17:59:58] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly... [17:59:58]
>   I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [18:00:01] E/launcher -
>   session not created exception from unknown error:
>   Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':
>   {"auxData":{"frameId":"9784.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2824.0) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.22.397933
>   (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) [18:00:01] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception from unknown error:
>   Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':
>   {"auxData":{"frameId":"9784.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2824.0) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.22.397933
>   (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) at WebDriverError (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:26:26)
>   at SessionNotCreatedError
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:307:26)
>   at Object.checkLegacyResponse
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:15)
>   at parseHttpResponse
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
>   at
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:11
>   at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
>   at TaskQueue.execute_
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
>   at TaskQueue.executeNext_
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
>   at
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25
>   at
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
>   From: Task: WebDriver.createSession() at Function.createSession
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:329:24)
>   at Driver
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:778:38)
>   at Direct.getNewDriver
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:68:26)
>   at Runner.createBrowser
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:187:43)
>   at
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:261:30
>   at _fulfilled
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
>   at self.promiseDispatch.done
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
>   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
>   at
>   c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
>   at runSingle
>   (c:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>   [18:00:01] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see
>   launcher [18:00:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
>   Process finished with exit code 199

**My config js look like below:**

```
     exports.config = { 
          directConnect: true, // Capabilities to be passed
          //to the webdriver instance. 
         capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome', },
         framework: 'jasmine2',
         specs: ['./src/sli_sanitytests/San1_Check_
                        Sli_Homepage_is_Accessible_spec.js',
                 './src/sli_sanitytests/San2_
                  Click_createButton_to_Open_Sli_CreateForm_page_spec.js',
                 './src/sli_sanitytests/San3_
                  Create_Sli_reference_spec.js' ], 
               suites: { 
                         smoke: ['./smoke/!*.spec.js'],
                         regression:['./regression/!*.spec.js'],
                         functional: ['./functional/!*.spec.js'],
                         all: ['./!*!/!*.spec.js'],
                         selected:['./functional/addcustomer.spec.js',
                                    './regression/openaccount.spec.js'],
                         },
                       // Options to be passed to Jasmine
                  jasmineNodeOpts: {
                 //onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.                                
                  onComplete: null, 
                 // If true, display spec names. 
                 isVerbose: true, // If true,print colors to the terminal. 
                 showColors: true, // If true, include stack traces in       
                                   //failures. 
                 includeStackTrace: true, // Default time to wait in ms  
                                         //before a test fails.  
                 defaultTimeoutInterval: 80000 
                             },
                //enter code here 
               onPrepare:function() { 
                   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
                   browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
               },
             }
```

Comment: Which protractor version are you using? seems that you are getting `uncaught exception` that can be due to various reasons!

Comment: Hoping this helps someone else...I faced this same issue as the OP after a Windows update to my machine. Turns out that reinstalling Protractor solved the issue. i.e. first run `npm install protractor -g`, then `webdriver-manager update` to update the chrome driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all uninstall your chrome browser and reinstall it. That`s it protractor will not throw any such errors.

I even don`t know why this happened and for what reasons looks bit strange but yes the only solution is uninstall the chrome browser and reinstall it.

npm uninstall webdriver-manager -g npm install webdriver-manager -g

Answer (score 40):

**2016-10-13**: [ChromeDriver v2.24](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) has been released which supports Chrome v52-54. (Thanks @Anton)

---

**2016-08-16**: One of the recent updates to the Chrome Dev channel introduced a bug preventing ChromeDriver from properly starting. Having just worked around the same problem, I would suggest backing up your data and reverting to the Beta or Stable release channel of Chrome. See the [Chrome Release Channels](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-How-do-I-choose-which-channel-to-use-) for more details on safely switching.

Alternatively, switching to the Dev version of ChromeDriver *should* also fix the issue. From a [closed issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1464#c2) on the chromedriver project:

> There are some Devtool changes in Chrome dev channel v54 which is not currently supported in Chromedriver stable v2.23. 
>   You may want to use dev version of Chromedriver which has the fix. It can be downloaded from `chromedriver…/continuous/….zip`

Review the issue for the full link.

Answer (score 14):

If the latest protractor is not having the [latest chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) then to update it using webdriver-manager follow these below steps

enter latest chromedriver version in file config.json this file is present under path */node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built*

optional (and change 'mac32' to 'mac64' in file 'chrome_driver.js' which is present under path */webdriver-manager/built/lib/binaries*)

run `webdriver-manager update` in the console.

**hint**: To get the path of 'webdriver-manager' folder observe the console after command `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: This is the simplest solution, today in 2016, for this recurring problem with Chrome updates

Comment: I didn't have to change the mac32 to mac64 thing. I just updated the version to 2.25 (now latest as of Oct 25, 2016) and ran `webdriver-manager update`.

Answer (score 6):

Since I got the same issue and found this question, I'd like to add a bit more context: it is indeed a version problem between an 'old' chrome driver (2.22 in my case) and a 'newer' chrome release (54 in my case) like Sean answered.

However there is no need to fiddle manually with config files or downloads.

Instead just run

```
npm update protractor -g
```

To update protractor globally then

```
webdriver-manager update
```

To update the chrome driver. The newer chrome driver v2.25 is not yet included in the protractor package at the time of writing (you will get v2.24 instead) but it works fine with Chrome 54. Protractor is v4.09 at the time of writing. The same trick should work for future versions too!

Comment: Thanks Cebe, your solution worked for me. I'd also update protractor locally since your internal code files will use the local one with "npm install protractor --save-dev"; the "--save-dev" flag will update it in the package.json file.

Comment: You're right, although it depends on your setup :-) In the question (and in my case), a global instance of protractor is used. We can see that looking at the path `...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\...`

Answer (score 2):

After big battle with above issue i have found the solution for it. So please
don`t do anything.

First of all uninstall your chrome browser and reinstall it. That`s it protractor will not throw any such errors.

I even don`t know why this happened and  for what reasons looks bit strange but yes the only solution is uninstall the chrome browser and reinstall it.

npm uninstall webdriver-manager -g
npm install webdriver-manager -g

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with 2.24 version. In order to fix this bug download chromedriver.exe with version 2.25, it's available now by link https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall webdriver-manager

```
npm uninstall webdriver-manager -g
npm install webdriver-manager -g
```

Issue was fixed for me after I installed webdriver-manager: 10.2.8

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue, I faced it many times.

I use chromedriver in my selenium framework once in month and I usually get this type of error.

Follow below steps:

1. Unistall/Remove all existing chromedriver.
2. Install latest
   chromedriver from official [google site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).
3. Set system path to chromedriver.exe folder *(So you don't need to bother about setting the system path from code)*
4. Restart the IDE *(If already running)*
5. ENJOY !

Answer (score 1):

I updated to Chrome Driver 2.25 which fixed the problem for me.  This is a simple update:

- Download the latest version from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
- Unzip the contents (it's one file "chromedriver.exe").
- Copy that over your existing chromedriver.exe
- For me that was at: \node_modules\protractor\selenium

That's it.  I reran the tests and the pesky error went away.