# Python selenium unknown error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have a python code that I run on my Windows computer roughly once a month,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('url')
```

last time I ran it everything was fine, but today I got this

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 
\'context\': {"auxData":{"frameId":"184.1","isDefault":true},
"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)\n  
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

I have tried reinstalling selenium but that didn't change anything.
I haven't included the full code since it breaks right at the beginning. 
Any input would be helpful

Comment: No worries, couldn't edit it. What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1451

Comment: I have updated to the latest version available for anaconda after I got that error, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, since google didn't come out with new chromedriver. The new chrome window pops up but than it crashes giving me this error

Comment: The error is usually thrown when the driver version +browser version aren't in sync. If none of the solutions in the links above work, please add the following details to your question: 1. Selenium version, 2. Chromedriver version and 3. Chrome version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is usually thrown when the driver version and browser version aren't in sync - you either need to upgrade `chromedriver` or downgrade Chrome.