# Unable to start session in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am setting error saying that session cannot be created in log.
I have latest version of appium 1.4.16.1 and chrome driver 2.25 
I was able to run 2 or 3 days back but now am getting this error. 
Am trying to launch google apk in my real device samsung galazy s7 edge.

```
    > info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":     {"appPackage":"com.android.chrome","appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"215acd36","platformVersion":"6.0"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_73)
> info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
> info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session e22b5731-cc9e-498e-b9b8-25b13e8cc03f
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device 215acd36
> info: [debug] Setting device id to 215acd36
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: Unlocking screen
> info: [debug] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n io.appium.unlock/.Unlock"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: [debug] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n io.appium.unlock/.Unlock"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: [debug] Screen is unlocked, continuing
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
> info: Starting App
> info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
> info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
> info: [debug] No matching processes found
> info: [debug] Running bootstrap
> info: [debug] spawning: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.android.chrome -e disableAndroidWatchers false
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp"}
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
> info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'starting'
> info: Chromedriver: Set chromedriver binary as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe
> info: Chromedriver: Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %a))
> info: Chromedriver: No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
> info: Chromedriver: Spawning chromedriver with: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe --url-base=wd/hub --port=9515
> info: Chromedriver: [STDOUT] Starting ChromeDriver 2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a) on port 9515
> Only local connections are allowed.
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/status] with no body
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"\",\"status\":0,\"value\":{\"build\":{\"version\":\"alpha\"},\"os\":{\"arch\":\"x86_64\",\"name\":\"Windows NT\",\"version\":\"10.0\"}}}"
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"215acd36"}}}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"31bb74b2f9e98babac5164c0bb34cb16","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\...
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"215acd36"}}}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"137c2c62945cd07d985069de12d2167d","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\...
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"215acd36"}}}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"7ca8cb2ab512a0d163f2b5ca46420a04","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Device 215acd36 is not online\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d...
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"215acd36"}}}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"89eb16f014c1755ab4857b7c9ccfb2f7","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\...
> error: Chromedriver: Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'stopped'
> info: Chromedriver stopped unexpectedly on us, shutting down then calling back up with the on-die callback
> error: Chromedriver: Error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception
> from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"10020.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))
>     at JWProxy.command$ (lib/proxy.js:133:15)
>     at tryCatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
>     at bound (domain.js:284:14)
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.runBound (domain.js:297:12)
>     at run (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\es6.promise.js:89:39)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\es6.promise.js:100:28
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>     at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.microtask.js:17:13)
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
>  { [Error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception
> from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"10020.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))
>     at JWProxy.command$ (lib/proxy.js:133:15)
>     at tryCatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
>   httpCode: 200 }
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
> from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"10020.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)
>     at bound (domain.js:284:14)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))
>     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.runBound (domain.js:297:12)
>     at run (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\es6.promise.js:89:39)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\es6.promise.js:100:28
>     at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\node_modules\appium-jsonwp-proxy\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.microtask.js:17:13)
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"10020.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)))","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"10020.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)"},"httpCode":200,"origValue":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"10020.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.68)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 59119.310 ms - 1369 
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 46.412
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
> info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 215acd36 shell "am force-stop com.android.chrome"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
```

Comment: can any one help here.

Comment: Maybe this helps you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro

Comment: your chromedriver version seems not be v2.25, the log show the version is 2.18
("Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 ")