# Selenium Webdriver (ChromeDriver) - giving unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver for chrome browser and I get the below error when I run it. Tried using the chromedriver version - 2.9. The chrome browser does get invoked but says `Not secure` on the address bar with below exception. Any help to get this fixed appreciated.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"7520.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
(Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - Getting "Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context" error when i run Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, You just need to use 2.25 version of chrome driver i think  its solve your problem