# Selenium message:unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've red multiple topics on this subject and I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to navigate to a url by using a standalone selenium server in combination with the Rselenium package.

I've tried the solutions they are disussing here: [Protractor - Getting "Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context" error when i run Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro)

- I've updated protactor and the webdrive manager
- I've tried to uninstall and re-install chrome

This is the R code:

```html
url <- "https://www.social-enterprise.nl/wie-doen-het/" 
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
# Open the browser webpage
remDr$open()
#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate(url)
```

This is the error message I get.

```
Selenium message:unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 
'context': {"auxData":
{"frameId":"6568.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```